# MVC5 option group maintenance table for CRUD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What is the best approach for maintaining (CRUD) on an optiongroup list that is driven by two sql server tables?

The option group is like this and is driven simply by two tables (parent child)

```
OptionGroupOne
   ItemOne
   ItemTwo
OptionGroupTwo
   SecondItemOne
   SecondItemTwo
   etc…………….
```

Was thinking of just looping through in an unordered list?

I’m using entity framework 6 with MVC5 don't really want to use javascript.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, I can't find the context between CRUD and your tables and what your expected result is

Comment: OK I just want a way of editing the titles of each option group and the title of each group below it

Answer (score 0):

This is a long way if you don't seem to have anything ready yet... I bet that's the reason why no one wants to start explaining.

You should organise the Lists in nested ViewModels, the `OptionGroupViewModel` and the `ItemViewModel`. The `OptionGroupViewModel` has a `string` property for the name and a `List<ItemViewModel>` property for the children. So the main model should be a `List<OptionGroupViewModel>`.

In your `cshtml`, Using the `Html.EditorForModel()` extension method on a the latter, you should get some View Results already, the `EditorFor...` methods are quite intelligent and will generate views based on the data structure.

Now you will need a MVC Post method with the List as the model and you will find all updates there, You need to map them back to the Entity Framework model (or whatever kind of base model you have). As you mentioned in your comment above, you want just a "way of editing the titles of each option group and the title of each group". This would be pretty simple but is half way to CRUD, and Delete + Add are much trickier in that scenario.

Using frameworks like [Knockout JS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/using-web-api-1-with-entity-framework-5/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-5) is a big gain here but requires some learning and will introduce JavaScript to your project. The linked tutorial is for Web.Api but it will also work for MVC.